# How do I represent an LZW output in bytes?

Tags: compression, byte, lzw

I found an implementation of the LZW algorithm and I was wondering how can I represent its output, which is an int list, to a byte array.

I had tried with one byte but in case of long inputs the dictionary has more than 256 entries and thus I cannot convert.

Then I tried to add an extra byte to indicate how many bytes are used to store the values, but in this case I have to use 2 bytes for each value, which doesn't compress enough.

How can I optimize this?

Comment: (This post would get more visibility if tagged [tag:compression].)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As bits, not bytes. You just need a simple routine that writes an arbitrary number of bits to a stream of bytes. It simply keeps a one-byte buffer into which you put bits until you have eight bits. Then write than byte, clear the buffer, and start over. The process is reversed on the other side.

When you get to the end, just write the last byte buffer if not empty with the remainder of the bits set to zero.

You only need to figure out how many bits are required for each symbol at the current state of the compression. That same determination can be made on the other side when pulling bits from the stream.

Comment: Nice idea, but how can I decompress the output? I should decrypt the bits stream to a list of int again and how can I know if a single int is represented in how many bits?

Comment: You reconstruct the compression process on the decompression side, and then you will know how many bits the next symbol is.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting the point. If I compress a string in LZW and get [12, 284] as the output, then I convert in bits: 1100 100011100. Now I output 8 bits and complete the remaining with zeroes: 11001000 00011100 -> [200, 28]. Now starting from [200, 28] how do I get back to [12, 284]?

Comment: The number if bits in the first symbol is fixed. In the standard Unix compress LZW format, it is nine bits. The number of bits in each subsequent symbol is determined by the preceding data (going up as the dictionary grows), and so is known on both the decompressing end before decoding the next symbol.

Comment: You can look at the [source code for compress](https://github.com/vapier/ncompress/blob/ncompress-4.2.4/compress42.c) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

In his 1984 article on LZW, T.A. Welch did not actually state how to "encode codes", but described mapping "strings of input characters into fixed-length codes", continuing "use of 12-bit codes is common". (Allows bijective mapping between three octets and two codes.)
The [BSD `compress(1)` command](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/compress.html) didn't literally follow, but introduced a header, the interesting part being a specification of the *maximum* number if bits to use to encode an LZW *output code*, allowing decompressors to size decompression tables appropriately or fail early and in a controlled way. (But for the very first,) Codes were encoded with just the number of integral bits necessary, starting with 9.
An alternative would be to use [Arithmetic Coding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding), *especially* if using a model different from *every code is equally probable*.